# Autocorrect is not working for Huawei Ascend G600 (U8950N)

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, auto-correct

I just bought a new Huawei (running Ice Cream Sandwich). When I use the keyboard (both the Android and Huawei IME), the photo does not recognise any common words in English, and so it underlines them all as errors. It recognises the names from my contacts, but not the main dictionary.

I could, over time, add the whole English language to my personalized words list, but I would rather not!

Any suggestions for the problem?

Comment: Have you checked whether a local dictionary is installed for your language? some keyboards require this for that issue. Besides: How shall a photo recognize words? Is that a typo in your question, or did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

I have installed [Go Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gokeyboard) and deactivated the phone's default autocorrect and spell checker. This seems to have solved the autocorrect dictionary problem, and I'm happy. Seems to be an issue with the factory software from Huawei...maybe. Dunno.

Comment: I have this same issue. Would you mind outlining your steps to fully correcting the problem? Would be very helpful. I also saw a suggestion to use JellyBean Keyboard. Something about a missing dictionary